# Editing Symfony shortcut notation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symony 2.3.0 I can create a entity and shortcut notation using the command:

`php app/console generate:doctrine:entity --entity=TravelTravelBundle:User`

According to [Symfony's Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html), This creates a entity shortcut which can be called in the defaultcontroller using this function:

```
public function ReturnUserAction($Username)
    {

        $userobject = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('TravelTravelBundle:User')
            ->findByusername($Username);
        if($userobject != NULL) {
            return $this->render('TravelTravelBundle:Default:User.html.twig', 
                array(
                'username' => $userobject[0]->getUsername(),
                'email' => $userobject[0]->getEmail(),
                'fn' => $userobject[0]->getFn(),
                'sn' => $userobject[0]->getSn(),
                'password' => $userobject[0]->getPassword(),
                )
            );  
        }
        if(!isset($userobject) || $userobject == NULL || $userobject == "") {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("The Username:\"$Username\" does not exist");
        }
    }
```

How would I change this entity's shortcut notation to  `TravelTravel:Username`, instead of `TravelTravelUser` without erasing the current entity and generating a new one?

Comment: Add new entity class `class Username extends User {}`.

Comment: Yes but where is the shortcut "TravelTravel:Username" being stored? when I call  
`$userobject = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('TravelTravelBundle:User')
            ->findByusername($Username);` the `>getRepository('TravelTravelBundle:User')` 

is being read from somewhere? Where is that shortcut being kept and how do I edit it?

Comment: write what is the purpose, and maybe we can find a better solution

Comment: The purpose is, when I execute a mysql query using doctrine I want to be able to use `$userobject = $this->getDoctrine() ->getRepository('TravelTravelBundle:Username') ->findByusername($Username);` 

because `username` is more descriptive then using `User` and it looks cleaner. What is  `->getRepository('TravelTravelBundle:User')` anyways?